# How to map a request to a handler in IIS 7 using a native module

Tags: c++, iis-7, httpmodule

I would like to build a native module (in C++) that handles mapping requests to handlers. So far the only example I have found is [here](http://learn.iis.net/page.aspx/169/develop-a-native-cc-module-for-iis/).

In particular, I need to know how to map a request to a managed handler.

So, does anyone have any examples of using `CHttpModule::OnMapRequestHandler`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I found the answer to my question [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms694237%28v=vs.90%29.aspx).

It looks like you need to call the `SetScriptMap` method of the `IMapHandlerProvider` using a custom `IScriptMapInfo` object.